# How to get previous page number in ajax jquery pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a pagination links to display data which include previous and next button.

What I want to do is when user clicks on previous link then the previous page's data should be displayed. I have a problem to get the previous page number.
Here is what I have done so far

```
$total_records=$this->db->count_all('category_table');

$total_pages=ceil($total_records/5);

echo "<ul class='pagination' id='show_cat_info_pag'>";
echo "<li class='prev' id='123'><a>Previous</a></li>";
for($page_no=1;$page_no<=$total_pages;$page_no++)
{
    echo "<li id='".$page_no."' class='cat_list_cls'><a id='".$page_no."' class='show_cat_info_pag' style='cursor:pointer'>".$page_no."</a></li>";

}
echo "<li class='next'><a>Next</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Jquery file -

```
$('#show_cat_info_pag li').click(function () {


   var page_no = $(this).attr('id');
   var page_item = $(".pagination li").not('.prev,.next');
   var prev = $(".pagination li.prev");
   var next = $('.pagination li.next');

   jQuery('ul').children().removeClass('active');
   jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass('active')

   $.ajax({
       url:base_url+'admin/demo_function',
       type:'post',
       data:{page_no:page_no},
       success:function(data)
       {
           $('#dis_demo_res').html(data);

       }
   });

});
```

Comment: Not the correct solution but you can maintain counter for page number. Do `++` for next and `--` for previous.

Comment: I tried but that is not working properly. How can i check user has clicked on previous link? I i get that then i just need to decrease value of page_no  by 1